# Dynamically loading an external webpack bundled ngModule as a route handler

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-router

We want to divide our large frontend projects into multiple separately deployed projects which are easier to work with.  I am trying to include a bundled ngModule to handle a route from within another app.  The apps must be ignorant of each other's configuration.  The bundles will share some large dependencies(like Angular) via globals.  We don't need to shake across the bundles and we may just have to accept some duplicate dependencies.

The root router complains that

```
Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'TestsetModule'.
```

which leads me to believe the child module is not being angular compiled on load, or is not registering its module for some reason.  I think it may be necessary to manually compile the module, but I'm not sure how to use this https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler#compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync

The root app loads the child via a route:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
const load = require("little-loader");


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ``, loadChildren: () => new Promise(function (resolve) {
      load('http://localhost:3100/testset-module-bundle.js',(err: any) => {
        console.log('global loaded bundle is: ', (<any>global).TestsetModule )
        resolve((<any>global).TestsetModule)
      }
    )
  })}
];

export const HostRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

I also tried using angular router's string resolution syntax rather than this weird global thing you see but I had similar issues.

Here is the module which is being loaded, very standard except for the global export:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
//import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { LoggerModule, Level } from '@churro/ngx-log';

import { FeatureLoggerConfig } from './features/logger/services/feature-logger-config';


import { TestsetComponent } from './features/testset/testset.component';
import { TestsetRouting } from './testset.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        //MaterialModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        LoggerModule.forChild({
          moduleName: 'Testset',
          minLevel: Level.INFO
        }),
        TestsetRouting,
    ],
    declarations: [TestsetComponent],
    providers: [
      /* TODO: Providers go here */
    ]
})
class TestsetModule { }
(<any>global).TestsetModule = TestsetModule

export {TestsetModule as default, TestsetModule};
```

Here is the webpack configuration of the root bundle.  Note the global exports via the poorly named "ProvidePlugin".

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
const path = require('path');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const IgnorePlugin = require('webpack/lib/IgnorePlugin');
const PolyfillsPlugin = require('webpack-polyfills-plugin');
const WebpackSystemRegister = require('webpack-system-register');


module.exports = (envOptions) => {
    envOptions = envOptions || {};
    const config = {

        entry: {
          'bundle': './root.ts'
        },
        output: {

          libraryTarget: 'umd',
          filename: '[name].js',//"bundle.[hash].js",
          chunkFilename: '[name]-chunk.js',
          path: __dirname
          },
          externals: {

          },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.html'],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
                { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },

            ]
        },
        devtool: '#source-map',
        plugins: [
          new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'angular': '@angular/core',
            'ngrouter': '@angular/router',
            'ngxlog':'@churro/ngx-log'
          })

        ]
    };
    config.module.rules.push(
      { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: [
        'awesome-typescript-loader', 
        'angular-router-loader',
        'angular2-template-loader', 
        'source-map-loader'
      ] } 
    );
  }



    return config;
};
```

And here is the webpack configuration of the child bundle.  Note the "externals" which look for angular as a global.

```
module.exports = (envOptions) => {
    envOptions = envOptions || {};
    const config = {
        entry: {
          'testset-module-bundle': './src/index.ts'
        },
        output: {
          //library: 'TestsetModule',
          libraryTarget: 'umd',
          filename: '[name].js',//"bundle.[hash].js",
          chunkFilename: '[name]-chunk.js',
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
          },
          externals: {
            //expect these to come from the app that imported us
            // name to be required : name from global
             'angular': '@angular/core',
             'ngrouter': '@angular/router',
             'ngxlog': '@churro/ngx-log'       
          },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.html'],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
                { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },

            ]
        },
        devtool: '#source-map',
        plugins: [

        ]
    };

    config.module.rules.push(
      { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: [
        'awesome-typescript-loader', 
        'angular-router-loader',
        'angular2-template-loader', 
        'source-map-loader'
      ] }
    );
  }



    return config;
};
```

And for good measure here is my tsconfig file which 'awesome-typescript-loader' reads.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "app",
    "paths": {
      "@capone/*": [
        "*"
      ],
      "@angular/*": [
        "node_modules/@angular/*"
      ],
      "rxjs/*": [
        "node_modules/rxjs/*"
      ]
    }
  },

  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/node_modules", "compiled", "src/dev_wrapper_app"],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./compiled",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

If you're still reading, awesome.  I was able to get this working when both bundles are part of the same webpack config and the child module is just a chunk.  Angular is designed to do that.  But our use case is to have the children and parent be ignorant of each other until runtime.

Comment: Have you tried using `webpack-angular-externals`? https://github.com/mattlewis92/webpack-angular-externals#usage Read also https://medium.com/@trekhleb/how-to-create-aot-jit-compatible-angular-4-library-with-external-scss-html-templates-9da6e68dac6e#ef43

Comment: maybe bundled it into a npm module that you could install into your other projects.

Comment: i will take approach to bootstrap the main app ,create a child module, then with main app router module lazy load the child module. Ionic has this implementation on every page it create and the result is faster app boostrap. a good refrence to separate the main module and child module https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: I was wondering if you already got this fixed ? I'm looking for a solution of a similar use case. I've tried injecting a script-tag with a rollup or umd bundle also, but I'm getting errors all the time.

Answer (score 3):

As you have mentioned

> The apps must be ignorant of each other's configuration.

I had a similar problem in Angular2. I solved it by creating a sub-application. A separate sub-main.browser.ts and index.html file. It had its own dependencies, sharing the same node modules. Both main modules bootstrapping different app-component. We were working on Angular without angular-cli.

In webpack config, I added

```
entry: {

  'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
  'main' .   :     './src/main.browser.aot.ts',
  'sub-main' : '/src/sub-main.browser.ts'

},
```

and a more detailed HtmlWebpackPlugin. In the chunks, we load only modules that will be used in both the app. If we see polyfills is common.

```
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index.html',
    title: METADATA.title,
    chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
    metadata: METADATA,
    inject: 'head',
    chunks: ['polyfills','main']
  }),

  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index2.html',
    title: 'Sub app',
    chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
    metadata: METADATA,
     inject: 'head',
    filename: './sub-app.html',
    chunks: ['polyfills','sub-main']
  }),
```

The next task was to create separate endpoints for both sub apps for dev environment.

```
devServer: {
      port: METADATA.port,
      host: METADATA.host,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000
      },
      proxy: {
   "/sub-app": {
    target: "http://localhost:3009",
    bypass: function(req, res, proxyOptions) {
        return "/index2.html";
    }
  }
}
    },
```

Now when I build the project two different HTML files are generated. Each with their own javascript bundle dependencies and common assets. They can be deployed on a different server as well.

I was able to finish my POC with lots of trial and error. My suggestion will be to look a step above angular. See how webpack is deploying your current project. And If you can configure it to serve your purpose.

Comment: At this point though, the base applications knows about sub-main, correct?

Comment: That's neat.  It looks to me like your main application needs to rebuild when the sub-main changes.  I should have been more clear: that's what we were trying to avoid.

Comment: @JaimeTorres  The webpack acts as the root and the mains as a child. If you are considering the main app as base application. It won't know about the sub-main and vice-versa.

Comment: @light24bulbs
Yes, it does rebuild the whole application. But I believe we can configure webpack to rebuild only the updated sub-application.