# Create a plug and play plugin framework setup using Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, liferay-6, portlet, portal

My application was in IBM WebSphere portal, where we have a centralized theme for all the portlets. We build individual portlets with the specific features which are then installed from a page into the portal like as shown below.
[image]

So altogether we build a portal with lots of portlets (individual web application). In the portal we creates pages and drag and drop each of these portlets as per the requirements.

Now the requirement was that we are moving everything to Micro service Architecture with Angular4 as the front-end. Currently I am having an angular4 application having many UI components and features. I am posting this question to get some ideas or possibility whether it is possible to create a portal like IBM WebSphere/ Liferay in Angular 4 with having the following basic features:

- User/Team can create separate individual angular4 application, build and will be able to install/uninstall within the main application like porltets in portal (IBM WebSphere).
- User will be able to view all the installed Angular4 application and can create pages, drag and drop those application within a newly created page.
- Each separate Angular4 application (like portlets) installed will be using the main application theme.

Can anyone tell me whether this is doable. Do we have any framework setup in Angular4

Comment: This question is *WAY* too broad.  I know you posted a bounty to attract attention, and the bounty keeps the question from being closed, but the chance that anyone will offer any answers to this is extremely low.  The likely responses will more likely be "Yes it's possible, but no we aren't going to help you figure out all the steps involved".

Comment: However, it's just as likely that you might get a response like "No, that's a server side feature, not a client side feature."  I personally might fall into that camp;  creating apps, hosting them, installing and uninstalling them, that all falls into a server side behavior, and angular is not a server side framework.

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible ways I can think of is using webpack(or any other module bundler) to handle the various angular application.

You can check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018621/dynamically-loading-an-external-webpack-bundled-ngmodule-as-a-route-handler/47294821#47294821) to get a brief overview of how you can configure webpack.

In the end, Angular compile to javascript only. So, It will be possible. But the effort needed to maintain and test the overall application might be huge.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It would be really great if you can share with me some github repo where I can see your POC project

Comment: Hi @AlexMan, Unfortunately, I can't share my code without the management permission. The link I gave pretty much sums it up.

Comment: yea Its okay...I don't need the exact project...but a small working sample is enough to get a start.

Comment: @AlexMan Okay Buddy. If I get some free time, I will try to replicate a sample in a Github project but I can't guarantee anything. But if you go ahead with webpack or any such solutions, feel free to ask me anything.

Comment: My current project is going live. I deeply apologize but I am very busy now. It will take time to setup such a project which I lack currently. Alex, please try to explore more on webpack and other such tools. I can't guarantee I will be free soon.

Answer (score -1):

When re-designing a system, it is best to think about the problem you are trying to solve and solve for that use case. It feels like you're trying to recreate the same bad interface with Angular. The code may be new, but the user interface problems will still be there.

I would recommend ditching the portlet idea and creating 1 app with many modules. Angular was designed to be very modular so different teams can work on separate modules. You could then have some sort of settings page where you can turn the modules on and off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You have mentioned `You could then have some sort of settings page where you can turn the modules on and off` . How can we do that. Can you please suggest or share something which will be a great help for me. Actually overall my intention is that there will be one main application in which multiple team can create different modules and admin can add or remove those to the main application.

Comment: It could be something simple such as a list of toggle switches. If the toggle is ON, that module shows up. You can use the *ngIf directive to show elements based on this configuration [*ngIf Directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)